# asp.net core 2.0 Entity Framework how to access user profile

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to `EF` and trying to use it with `.net core 2.0`. I may be on the wrong track here and would appreciate any help. I have created a new web application in VS 2017 selected individual user account. I am now trying to build on this further by adding a user profile table to store various bits of information. The trouble I am having is then reading this as part of the `ApplicationUser`.

So far I have done the following.

In ApplicationUser I have created -

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfileData> ProfileData { get; set; }
}
```

Then in UserProfileData table, I have -

```
public class UserProfileData
{
    public int  Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Health { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Is the correct way to join the tables and how can I then access the health field in the account controller, Edit and Create views?

I currently have this in the Register method.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email 
            ,test_img ,Health = model.Health};  //I know this is wrong.
```

Any help would be great even if its just to say I am going about this in the wrong way.

I hope this was clear.

Thanks

Comment: If you are new to entity framework, consider using it with .net Framework first before going to .net core, if you are not already familiar with .net core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just extend the `ApplicationUser` with any data you want to store for the user's profile.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Health { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Right now in your code you have created a one-to-many relationship, which means a user can have multiple profiles (which is probably not what you want).

I suggest reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx) and in particular [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) to learn more about EF relationships.

Comment: Ahh yes, that would not be good. Thank you for the links! Ill have a read now. So I can just add profile Data to the ApplcationUser, cool thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help @MoStar

Comment: Or change the property to `public virtual UserProfileData ProfileData { get; set; }` to turn it into a 1:1 association.